Javascript animation queue
    export class AnimateElement {
        constructor(el) {
            this.el = el;
            this.animationQueue = [];
            this.handleAnimationEnd = this.handleAnimationEnd.bind(this);
        }

        addAnimation(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, delay, time, func = 'linear', direction = 'forwards', handler = null) {
            this.animationQueue.push({ fromx, fromy, tox, toy, delay, time, func, direction, handler });
console.log(this.animationQueue);
        }

        move() {
console.log('move called.', this.animationQueue.length, this.animationQueue);
            if (this.animationQueue.length > 0) {
                let oper = this.animationQueue.shift();

                let fromx = oper.fromx !== null ? oper.fromx : parseFloat(this.el.style.getPropertyValue('--translate-to-x')) || 0;
                let fromy = oper.fromy !== null ? oper.fromy : parseFloat(this.el.style.getPropertyValue('--translate-to-y')) || 0;

    console.log('fromx:', fromx, 'fromy:', fromy);

                this.el.style.setProperty('--translate-from-x', fromx + 'px');
                this.el.style.setProperty('--translate-from-y', fromy + 'px');
                this.el.style.setProperty('--translate-to-x', oper.tox + 'px');
                this.el.style.setProperty('--translate-to-y', oper.toy + 'px');
                this.el.style.setProperty('--animate-time', oper.time + 'ms');
                this.el.style.setProperty('--animate-func', oper.func);
                this.el.style.setProperty('--animate-delay', oper.delay + 'ms');
                this.el.style.setProperty('--animate-direction', oper.direction);
                this.el.currentAnimationHandler = oper.handler;
                this.el.addEventListener('animationend', this.handleAnimationEnd);
    console.log('added listener.');
                this.el.classList.add('animate-transform');
            }
        }

        handleAnimationEnd(event) {
    console.log('handleAnimationEnd called.');
            // Update the from coordinates to be the to coordinates for the next animation
            this.el.style.setProperty('--translate-from-x', this.el.style.getPropertyValue('--translate-to-x'));
            this.el.style.setProperty('--translate-from-y', this.el.style.getPropertyValue('--translate-to-y'));

            event.target.classList.remove('animate-transform');
            event.target.removeEventListener('animationend', this.handleAnimationEnd);
    console.log('removed listener.');
            if (this.el.currentAnimationHandler) {
                this.el.currentAnimationHandler();
            }
            this.move(); // Trigger the next animation in the queue
        }
    }


I have a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/va9skyj4/
Basically I am trying to create a javascript class that encapsulates a DOM element and that can add animations and then trigger them to run sequentially. The break of the code is two fold:

After the first animation is complete (which works perfectly), the next animation does not animate but just snaps to the end location.
Never continues after the second move.

Looking at the console.logs the animationend handler is called once only. While the handler removes itself from the element's listeners, the move method is called which re adds that same handler again.

I suggest you reduce the code and dependencies to a bare minimum. Try to reproduce this behaviour without bootstrap. Exclude anything that doesn't attribute to the problem.

I wish to answer my own question with this comment. The issue is I am using keyframes and when the animation ends, changing the animation variables (like tox and toy) will snap the element to match those changes, and setting the animationend listener does nothing (effectively) since the animation is already considered to be ended.

As posted in the comments section above, the issue was the keyframes animation was completed after the first animation, and as such changing the parameters would simply make the element move instantly, and adding animationend listeners would never be called since the animation has already ended. So I have created a simpler solution that removes the animation class and forces a reflow operation. See here:
function addTransform(animations, fromx, fromy, tox, toy, delay, time, func = 'linear', direction = 'forwards') {
    const typ = 'transform';
    animations.push({typ, fromx, fromy, tox, toy, delay, time, func, direction});
}

function animate(animationSteps, e) {
    if(animationSteps == null || animationSteps.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if e is an event object and replace it with the target element
    if (e instanceof Event) {
        e = e.target;

        // Ensure the animation is reset
        e.classList.remove('animate-transform');
        // Trigger a reflow, flushing the CSS changes
        void e.offsetWidth; // or e.offsetHeight;
    }

    let step = animationSteps.shift();
    switch(step.typ.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'transform':
            let fromx = step.fromx !== null ? step.fromx : parseFloat(e.style.getPropertyValue('--translate-to-x')) || 0;
            let fromy = step.fromy !== null ? step.fromy : parseFloat(e.style.getPropertyValue('--translate-to-y')) || 0;

            e.style.setProperty('--translate-from-x', fromx + 'px');
            e.style.setProperty('--translate-from-y', fromy + 'px');
            e.style.setProperty('--translate-to-x', step.tox + 'px');
            e.style.setProperty('--translate-to-y', step.toy + 'px');
            e.style.setProperty('--animate-time', step.time + 'ms');
            e.style.setProperty('--animate-func', step.func);
            e.style.setProperty('--animate-delay', step.delay + 'ms');
            e.style.setProperty('--animate-direction', step.direction);

            e.addEventListener('animationend', function handler(event) {
                event.target.removeEventListener('animationend', handler);
                animate(animationSteps, event);
            });
            e.classList.add('animate-transform');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

